# Configuring DNSMasq on a WZR-HP-G300NH

Tags: internal-dns, router, dnsmasq, buffalo

I'm looking to configure DNS naming on my [WZR-HP-G300NH router](http://www.buffalotech.com/products/wireless/routers-and-access-points/airstation-nfiniti-wireless-n-high-power-router-access-point-wzr-hp-g300nh/).  How would one go about doing this?  I have found the documentation for Dnsmasq [here](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/setup.html), and the place where it appears you can configure DNSMasq is located in the WZR-HP-G300NH configuration Web interface under Services->Services->DNSMasq->Additional DNSMasq Options

Does that textarea edit /etc/hosts or something?

Suppose I want to call my local domain, leerdomain.local, and I want to assign a name like "wp" to a static ipaddress on my local lan.

Router Model: WZR-HP-G300NH
Firmware Version: DD-WRT v24SP2-EU-US (08/19/10) std

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That text area probably edits dnsmasq.conf.

To accomplish your first request, use

```
expand-hosts
domain=leerdomain.local
```

That will automatically set up DNS entries based on hostnames. So when a computer named example requests an IP address via DHCP, a DNS record will be created that maps example.leerdomain.local to the IP address the computer received.

For your second request, the following would set up a DNS record that maps wp to 192.168.1.23. Substitute whatever IP address you need, of course.

```
address=/wp/192.168.1.23
ptr-record=wp,192.168.1.23
```

Comment: Yup that did it!  Here's the link to the dd-wrt documentation on that: http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/DNSMasq_-_DNS_for_your_local_network_-_HOWTO